# Obx Getx not updating real time in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-getx

I am retrieving a collection from firebase firestore. and it shows in my app. But when I manually change values in firebase it doesn't change in my Apps UI in real time. Changes only occur after a hot reload. I am using the Obx method

Here is my modal page

```
StoreModel storeModelFromJson(String str) => StoreModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String storeModelToJson(StoreModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class StoreModel {
    StoreModel({
       required this.image,
       required this.name,
       required this.description,
       required this.type,
    });

    String image;
    String name;
    String description;
    String type;

    factory StoreModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StoreModel(
        image: json["image"],
        name: json["Name"],
        description: json["description"],
        type: json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "image": image,
        "Name": name,
        "description": description,
        "type": type,
    };
}
```

Here's my GetxController class

```dart
class StoreController extends GetxController{
  
  var storeList = <StoreModel>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
   
    fetchRecords();
    super.onInit();
  }

  fetchRecords()async{
    var records =await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('store_products').get();
    showProducts(records);
  }
   
  showProducts(QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> records) {
   var listDb = records.docs.map((item) => StoreModel(
      image:item['Image'], 
      name: item['Name'], 
      description:item['description'], 
      type: item['type']
      )
      ).toList();
 
      if(records != null){
        storeList.value = listDb;
      }
      return storeList;
  }  
}
```

And below is where I use Obx

```dart
Obx(()=> GridView.builder(
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    childAspectRatio: 2 / 3),
    itemCount:controller.storeList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return StoreItemWidget(
        storeItem: controller.storeList[index],
      );
    },
  )
)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but it makes perfect sense that your code doesn't work with realtime changes in your database. Your code just retrieves the data as it is at that moment, a snapshot. You need some kind of stream for live updates, but I have no idea how that works with firebase

Comment: Have a look at the Firebase documentation on [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), which even contains a code sample of using a `StreamBuilder` to do so.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the `get` function to fetch data from firestore which is a one-time call.

```dart
var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('store_products').get();
```

The `get` function fetches the values from firebase only once. If you want to update your Ui in real-time as the value change in the firestore then use `stream` instead of `future`.

The `snapshot` function returns the stream, listening to the stream will update the value as its changes in the firestore.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('store_products')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {

         
        });
```

Here is the full code:

```dart
class StoreController extends GetxController {
  final storeList = <StoreModel>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    fetchRecords();
  }

  void fetchRecords() {
    List<StoreModel> list = [];

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('store_products')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> event) {

      list.clear(); //To avoid duplicating items

      for (var item in event.docs) {

        StoreModel model = StoreModel(
          image: item.get('Image'),
          name: item.get('Name'),
          description: item.get('description'),
          type: item.get('type'),
        );

        list.add(model);
      }

      storeList.assignAll(list);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `storeList.refresh()` in your `getxcontroller` or call `update()` function.

Comment: can you please explain that. iam new to flutter and self learning

Comment: if(records != null){
        storeList.value = listDb;
      }          =======>storyList.clear();
storeList.addAll(listDb);       i think it will be work sorry also i am amateur...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).